# stored procedure exists details not validate

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Im create the stored procedure , I want to check `UserCategoryCode` and `UserCategoryName`, existing record, im make a `existing record` , but not a correctly working it  for the `UserCategoryCode,` how can i do it? im try to do it, but not work, (Its work for the `UserCategoryName` )

**SP**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserCategories_InsertUpdate]
@UserCategoryId int,
@UserCategoryCode   varchar(50),
@UserCategoryName varchar(250),
@Remarks nvarchar(max),
@StatusId int,
-- @StatusChangeDate DATETIME,
@CreateId int,
@Mode varchar(50),
@iOutput int output

AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN


    IF @Mode = 'Add'
    BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT UserCategoryCode,UserCategoryName FROM UserCategories WHERE  UserCategoryCode = @UserCategoryCode AND UserCategoryName = @UserCategoryName) 
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO  UserCategories(

                 UserCategoryCode,
                 UserCategoryName, 
                 StatusId,
                 StatusChangeDate,
                 CreateBy,
                 CreatedDate,
                 Remarks 

                 )
                 VALUES(
                 @UserCategoryCode,
                 @UserCategoryName,
                 @StatusId,GETDATE(),
                 @CreateId,GETDATE(),
                 @Remarks


                 )



        SET @iOutput = 1 --save successful--
        END

        ELSE

        BEGIN
            SET @iOutput=-3 --existing record--
        END
    END
    ELSE IF @Mode = 'Modify'
    BEGIN

                        UPDATE  UserCategories

                        SET UserCategoryCode   =   @UserCategoryCode,
                            UserCategoryName  = @UserCategoryName,
                            StatusId = @StatusId,
                            Remarks  = @Remarks,
                            EditBy   = @CreateId, 
                            EditDate =  GETDATE()


                        WHERE  UserCategoryId = @UserCategoryId

                        SET @iOutput = 2    --save successful-- 

    END 

    COMMIT 

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        print ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SET @iOutput = -2   --sp error--
        ROLLBACK        
    END CATCH

END
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all...)

Comment: Sir, thanks for the advice and im not clear, can you please explain it,im a beginner for the SQL , i like to learn and ,im accepted your advice :) did you mean ` (standard, there are different versions of the SQL language.However, to be compliant with the ANSI standard, they all support at least the major commands) `

Comment: SQL is a language specified by ANSI/ISO. Most dbms products have a SQL implementation close to that standard. However, when it comes to stored procedures most products have their own versions. Your code is not ANSI SQL compliant. If you tag the dbms you're using, your question will get better attention and better answers - faster!

Comment: Sir ,Thanks for the advice, understood

Comment: So, which dbms product are you using? (Perhaps SQL Server?)

Comment: Sir , only  SQL  saver

Answer (score 1):

oh finally its working , i found the solution ,

`IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT UserCategoryCode FROM UserCategories WHERE  UserCategoryCode = @UserCategoryCode)`
    `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT UserCategoryName FROM UserCategories WHERE   UserCategoryName = @UserCategoryName)`

```
BEGIN

            INSERT INTO  UserCategories(

                 UserCategoryCode,
                 UserCategoryName, 
                 StatusId,
                 StatusChangeDate,
                 CreateBy,
                 CreatedDate,
                 Remarks 

                 )
                 VALUES(
                 @UserCategoryCode,
                 @UserCategoryName,
                 @StatusId,GETDATE(),
                 @CreateId,GETDATE(),
                 @Remarks


                 )



        SET @iOutput = 1 --save successful--
        END

        ELSE

        BEGIN
            SET @iOutput=-3 --existing record--
        END
        ELSE

        BEGIN
            SET @iOutput=-5 --existing record--
        END

    END
    ELSE IF @Mode = 'Modify'
    BEGIN

                        UPDATE  UserCategories

                        SET UserCategoryCode   =   @UserCategoryCode,
                            UserCategoryName  = @UserCategoryName,
                            StatusId = @StatusId,
                            Remarks  = @Remarks,
                            EditBy   = @CreateId, 
                            EditDate =  GETDATE()


                        WHERE  UserCategoryId = @UserCategoryId

                        SET @iOutput = 2    --save successful-- 

    END 

    COMMIT 

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        print ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SET @iOutput = -2   --sp error--
        ROLLBACK        
    END CATCH

END
```

**and code behind**

```
 else if (output == -3)
                {
                    lblMsg.Text = "Already Exists!";
                    lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                }

                else if (output == -5)
                {
                    lblMsg.Text = "Already Exists!";
                    lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                }
```